# How soon should I cut up new wood?

Tags: wood, wood-drying

I scored some pretty good logs of cherry from some workers across the street from my house who would rather have given it to me than lift it into the back of their truck. I carted it home and have it laying beside my house under some covering for right now. I plan on slabbing it up and piling it to dry for use in projects in a couple of years. My problem is I won't be able to get to the cutting it up portion for at least another week or so due to previous engagements. **How long can I wait to cut up the wood before any adverse effects such as major warping or rot start to occur?**

Comment: You're fine waiting a while before you cut up some green wood, after all they don't get to every log in the sawmill the day it's felled. But, you should immediately take steps to seal the end grain if the sections of log aren't sizeable as this will greatly reduce the chance of end checks and other defects from the wood drying too quickly. See the **Related** column to the right for more on drying wood here on SE, although there's tons more info on this elsewhere online.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much a duplicate of previous Q&A.

Comment: A lot depends on your local climate. I'm assuming you're not in New England. If you are somewhere not too hot, and with a relatively high humidity, the logs won't dry too fast, and a week won't be a big problem. If you're hot and dry, you need to act quickly.  Slap a coat of latex paint on the exposed ends. And be careful about allowing enough ventilation on the drying slabs. Spalting is attractive sometimes, but it 's not usually welcome on cherry.